# Avoiding pumping lemma

Tags: automata, regular-languages, context-free, proof-techniques, pumping-lemma

Is there a way to show $\{a^nb^nc^n:n\geq0\}$ is not regular without pumping lemma?

Comment: The suggested duplicate is for the first question. Please keep in mind that post should contain one question and some research prior to asking is required (checking similar questions and using the search engine counts).

Comment: 1. We prefer that you ask only one question per post.  If you have multiple questions, you can post them separately.  I've edited out the second question.  If you'd like to post it separately, you can find it in the revision history (look for the part that says 'edited...').  2. What research have you done?  Have you searched this site?  Have you looked in textbooks?  You should search before asking, and we want to know what you've already done, and what your thoughts are.